# como crear una funcion en python para repartir cartas

Tags: python

Considerando el siguiente código que crea el mazo como una lista:

```
def crear_mazo(palo, color)
    simbolos = ['AS', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'J', 'Q', 'K']
    i = 0
    mazo = []
    while i < len(simbolos):
        valor = i + 1
        simbolo = simbolos[i]
        carta = valor, simbolo, palo, color
        mazo.append(carta)
    return mazo
```

1. Construya una función que, a partir de un mazo (recibido por parámetro), reparta aleatoriamente una cantidad de cartas dadas (recibido también por parámetros).
2. Presente el resultado considerando el siguiente programa principal:

```py
mazo = []

mazo.extend(crear_mazo('Corazones', 'Rojo'))
mazo.extend(crear_mazo('Diamantes', 'Rojo'))
mazo.extend(crear_mazo('Treboles', 'Negro'))
mazo.extend(crear_mazo('Picas', 'Negro'))
cartas = repartir_cartas(mazo, 5)
print(cartas)
```

necito crear una funcion que reparta 5 cartas agradezco cualquier ayuda

Comment: Buenos días Santiago. Parece la pregunta de un trabajo de clase. Para empezar, podrías exponer el código con lo que has intentando hasta el momento. No estamos en stackoverflow para resolver problemas de clase. Un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

El método para crear las cartas se puede reducir con comprensión de listas:

```
def crear_mazo(palo, color):
    simbolos = ['AS', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'J', 'Q', 'K']
    mazo = [(i + 1, simbolos[i], palo, color) for i in range(len(simbolos))]
    return mazo
```

Para extraer las cartas debes ir eliminandolas del mazo:

```
def extraer_cartas(mazo, numero):
    mano = []
    while numero > 0 and mazo:
        i = random.randint(0, len(mazo) - 1)
        mano.append(mazo.pop(i))
        numero -= 1

    return mano
```

El método parte con una mano vacía e itera hasta llenarla con la cantidad pedida de cartas (y claro, mientras queden cartas en el mazo).

En cada iteración se genera un índice al azar entre 0 y el largo del mazo en ese momento. Esa carta se extrae del mazo con `pop()` y se agrega a la mano.

#### Demo

```
import random


def crear_mazo(palo, color):
    simbolos = ['AS', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'J', 'Q', 'K']
    mazo = [(i + 1, simbolos[i], palo, color) for i in range(len(simbolos))]
    return mazo

def extraer_cartas(mazo, numero):
    mano = []
    while numero > 0 and mazo:
        i = random.randint(0, len(mazo) - 1)
        mano.append(mazo.pop(i))
        numero -= 1

    return mano

mazo = []

for palo, color in [('Corazones', 'Rojo') , ('Diamantes', 'Rojo'),  ('Treboles', 'Negro'),  ('Picas', 'Negro')]:
    mazo.extend(crear_mazo(palo, color))

for carta in extraer_cartas(mazo, 5):
    print(carta)
```

produce:

```
(12, 'Q', 'Treboles', 'Negro')
(9, '9', 'Picas', 'Negro')
(3, '3', 'Diamantes', 'Rojo')
(3, '3', 'Corazones', 'Rojo')
(6, '6', 'Corazones', 'Rojo')

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 0):

La pregunta es un poco confusa, así que puede que no te esté respondiendo exactamente a lo que preguntas, pero si con "repartir 5 cartas", te refieres a generar una lista con 5 cartas al azar de la baraja, sería tan fácil como usar `random.choices`. Así:

```py
import random
def repartir_cartas(mazo, n):
    return random.samples(mazo, n)
```

Si además quieres eliminar las cartas seleccionadas de la baraja, puedes hacer algo como:

```py
import random
def repartir_cartas(mazo, n):
    res = []
    for _ in range(n):
        i = random.randint(0, len(mazo)-1)
        res.append(mazo.pop(i))
    return res
```